# UNIQUE constraint on a specific pairing

Tags: postgresql, database-design, unique-constraint

I am trying to work out a special `UNIQUE` constraint: there are many columns in a `Users` table but only these two are relevant for the question:

```
id bigint,
active boolean,
...
```

I want to allow multiple rows to have the same `id` - **but** only one of them may have `active = true`.

E.g. There can be many rows with `id = 1` and `active = false`, but only one can have `id = 1` and `active = true`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this, you can make use of a very useful PostgreSQL feature - that of the `partial index`.

You have your table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
  id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  --
  -- other fields
  --
  active BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);
```

Then, you do:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON foo (id) 
WHERE active;  -- if you prefer more clarity, could have "WHERE active = TRUE;"
```

So, we try it out (see the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d9f169953fe192cb883f38db3646172e)):

```
--
-- `active` - all false for a given id - works
--
INSERT INTO foo 
VALUES (1, FALSE), (1, FALSE), (1, FALSE);
```

check:

```
SELECT * FROM foo;
```

Result:

```
id  active
1   f
1   f
1   f
```

Another possibility - the specific one pertaining to the question:

```
--
-- one and only one `active` = true for a given id - works
--
INSERT INTO foo 
VALUES (2, FALSE), (2, FALSE), (2, TRUE);
```

Check:

```
SELECT * FROM foo;
```

Result:

```
id  active
1   f
1   f
1   f
2   f
2   f
2   t
```

Final test:

```
--
--  attempt to INSERT two true `active` values for a given id - fails!
--
INSERT INTO foo
VALUES (3, FALSE), (3, FALSE), (3, TRUE), (3, TRUE);
```

Result:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "foo_id_idx"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(3) already exists.
```

The `foo` table is unchanged, which is what we want!

Comment: Awesome - Thanks very much!

Comment: @GavinBaumanis If you feel that the answer is correct, please mark it as such. It may help those with a similar issue into the future - answers marked as correct tend to rise to the top in searches! p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: @GavinBaumanis: If that answers your question properly, please consider *accepting* it.